# Overlapping commands?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a fun little discord chat bot with JavaScript and node.js and I'd like to put in a specific command without it affecting another one I already have set up.

She works wonderfully on all the servers I have her on, and I've got it set up so that when someone in the server says anything with "rei are", she responds with a constant from areResponses.

```js
//const!!!
const areResponses = ["HELL yeah!", "Yep!", "I'm pretty sure that's true!", "I\'m not gonna put all the responses here because then it'd be too long..."];

//theres some other bot stuff (console log, now playing) under here but it isn't relevant until...

//the basics...
      if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("rei are")) {
          var response = areResponses [Math.floor(Math.random()*areResponses.length)];

          message.channel.send(response).then().catch(console.error);
      }
```

What I want to have happen is, preferably, this command to function without setting off the "rei are" command I coded in.

```js
if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes("rei are you happy")) {
           message.channel.send("Yes, absolutely.");
       }
```

As of right now, whenever I try to input the above command, it just triggers the "rei are" command AND the "rei are you happy" command with two messages...

Comment: String.prototype.includes() will match any string that contains 'rei are'. So anything you write with that inside will trigger the first found test case. You can move the function above the 'rei are' test so it can be evaluated first, or simply compare a exact match.

Comment: @NickLeBlanc That still has both commands trigger at the same time, it just puts the "rei are you gay" response before the "rei are" response. Is there any way of stopping the "rei are" test from triggering entirely for this just this command?

Comment: Return the function to stop the execution flow or put both tests on a If() {} else if() {} statement.

Comment: @NickLeBlanc You should probably consider turning your comments as answers to the post.

Comment: @NickLeBlanc that works great! thanks for the input!!

Comment: No problem, you can always answer your own question and Mark as accepted

Answer (score 1):

else/if chains work beautifully for this actually!!!

```js
      if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes("rei do you like girls")) {
            message.channel.send("Yes, absolutely. Girls are just... yeah...");
         }
      else if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("rei are")) {
          var response = areResponses [Math.floor(Math.random()*areResponses.length)];

          message.channel.send(response).then().catch(console.error);
        }
```

All you need to do is put the command that would overlap with the larger commands at the very bottom of the else if chain, and then you're good!!