# How to make a bot not respond to itself, but still respond to other bots?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm back on the grind of working with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55989150/overlapping-commands) [discord bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012519/basic-one-message-dice-roller), and at this point, I've gotten so attached to her that I decided to whip up a couple of companion bots for her that she can respond back and forth with in little conversations! The thing is, to allow her to talk with the other bots, I simply deleted this line of code...

```js
if (message.author.bot) return;
```

...and it turns out, that had some repercussions I probably should've expected, and as soon as I brought up her rei!help command, it set off *every single one of her other commands*...

Are there any alternatives to the code above that I can use so that she only doesn't respond to her own messages? I've seen `(message.userID === bot.userID)` used, but for my bot, it just locks up and doesn't respond to anything if I copypaste that code in. It doesn't bring up an error message either...

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: clairification for what's around the line of code here!

```js
///constants and dependencies above here

//console log
bot.on('ready',() => {
   console.log('Up and running!!!');
});

//set 'playing' to
bot.on('ready', () => {
 bot.user.setActivity('hehe clairvoyance time')
});

//bot stuff
bot.on('message', message => {
  // heres the stuff so reibot doesnt go ham every time someone does rei!help
  if (message.author.bot) return;

///all commands below here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the ID of the author is that of the client. That way, it'll ignore any messages sent by itself (and only itself).

```js
if (message.author.id === client.user.id) return;
```

Comment: That still makes it freeze up, sorry. 
I can give the code *around* the command though if that helps!

Comment: Yes please, context would help identify the problem.

Comment: Edited the original post to have the outside code!!

Comment: Just to be clear, you're replacing the whole if statement shown in your message event, correct?

Comment: All it really does is just not respond to any commands I try and put in, so if i try something like say rei!help, it doesn't do anything in response.

Comment: Add `console.log('message received')` immediately after checking that the author isn't the bot. Then check the console when you send a message, and that way you can see what's going on. It might be other code you have that isn't working.

Comment: Hm... If i swap in the `if (message.author.id === client.user.id) return;` then it just doesn't pick up messages at all..

Comment: Is there any error? Is `client` your Discord Client (it might be `bot` instead)?

Comment: Oh, that was probably the issue, it works now! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! If this answer solves your problem, feel free to accept it with the checkmark to the left of it.